# How to remove background color for the sized box in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The background color is coming for the elevated button in flutter. I have added a background image for the elevated button, but the background color( blue and grey color ) is coming for it. I do not know where it is coming from. So how to remove it?

```
    child:SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Wrap(
          alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
          runSpacing:  20.0, // Or more
          spacing: 20, // Or more
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 520,
            ),

            SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity, // <-- Your width
                height: 50, // <-- Your height

            ),
            SizedBox(
                height: 80, // <-- Your height
                width: 80,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    onGoogleSignIn(context);
                  },
                  child: Image.asset('images/gm.png')
                ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
                height: 80, // <-- Your height
                width: 80,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    //validateForm();
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => const PhoneLoginScreen()));
                  },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.red.withOpacity(0),
                    ),

                    child: Image.asset('images/mn.png')
                ),// Button
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: SizedBox don't have backgroundcolor. You see parent widget backgroundcolor. Yo can replace SizedBox with Conatiner and set color for Container or remove Sizedbox.

Comment: @SulaymonNe'matov: Can you edit my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution is :
Make Elevation - 0

```
  style: ButtonStyle(
          color: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
          elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(0), //Defines Elevation
       
        ),
```

Comment: this is not working

Comment: use color transparent and elevation 0

Comment: getting error: color is not defined

Comment: it should work check the spelling please

Answer (score 0):

you can try another option to make similar

```
InkWell(
 onTap:(){},
 splashColor: .... // this will add ripple effect
 child: Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Image.asset('images/mn.png')
 )
```

Comment: Your answer is not correct, opacity: 0 of any color will return a transparent color and in the case of the elevatedButton the gray background is due to the elevation of the button which has a default value of 2, just check the styleFrom.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the elevation causing the issue. Use Ink with InkWell to make an image button. Given your image is circular, you can use the border-radius to limit the splash.

```
class ImageButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const double size = 80;
    const String imageUrl = "https://picsum.photos/512";

    return SizedBox(
      width: size,
      height: size,
      child: Ink(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: const DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(imageUrl)),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(size / 2),
        ),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(size / 2),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Check the example in [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=361c2057e8d75d22b541a3a9c82fec10)